# How To Add Role Id to Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have gotten the role id of the user and I want to update another model that contains a column for roleid but it always says can not convert generic list to string and I convert the gotten role id to string but do not get the value and I want to add it to the model.

This is what I have so far

```
var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user); 
var roleIds = _roleManager.Roles
    .Where(r => role.AsEnumerable().Contains(r.Name))
    .Select(r => r.Id)
    .ToList();
```

This is the exception code. When I change to ToString that do not get any value

```
var roleIds = _roleManager.Roles
    .Where(r => role.AsEnumerable().Contains(r.Name))
    .Select(r => r.Id)
    .ToString(); 

userEmployee.Stations.Add(new Models.AppModel.StaffStation { RoleId = roleIds })
```

And I only want to update not even create new. I am new to .net

Comment: Can you show the code which throws exception you are talking about?

Comment: var roleIds = _roleManager.Roles.Where(r => role.AsEnumerable().Contains(r.Name)).Select(r => r.Id).ToString();                                                           userEmployee.Stations.Add(new Models.AppModel.StaffStation { RoleId = roleIds })         And I only want to update not even create new. I am new to .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

continuous on Fabio's answer you can check if the user in the role before adding to your model as below

```
     //Get All User Roles
        var userRoles = roleManager.Roles.Where(r => role.AsEnumerable().Contains(r.Name));

        //Loop on All User Roles
        foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
        {
            //Check if User not in role so we will add it
            if(!await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, userRole.Name))
            {
                var station = new Models.AppModel.StaffStation { RoleId = userRole.Id };
                userEmployee.Stations.Add(station);
            }
            else
            {
                //here you can check if you don't need this role for this user anymore so delete it
                //or keep it as is
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: the var station is getting an error since I have declared it before in a local scope

Comment: Please share the class of StaffStation

Comment: var userEmp = new ApplicationUser { Email = employee.Email, UserName = employee.Email, AreaId = station.AreaId, ZoneId = station.ZoneId };
                userEmp.Stations = new List<Models.AppModel.StaffStation>();

               
               
                userEmp.Stations.Add(new Models.AppModel.StaffStation { Staff = userEmployee, Station = _context.Stations.Single(x => x.Id == employee.StationId) });

Comment: What I am doing is adding a role and creating a new user giving password and email as well. So after updating the staffstation I add user to role then get the role id of the user and add to the staffstation

Comment: try this approch : userEmp.Stations = new List<Models.AppModel.StaffStation>();
            //Use single or default instead of single and check if return value not equal null
            var staffStation = _context.Stations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == employee.StationId);
            if (staffStation != null)
            {
                //use Staff Id and Station Id Instead of using Refrence property of ( Staff and Station)
                userEmp.Stations.Add(new Models.AppModel.StaffStation
                { StaffId = userEmployee.Id, StationId = staffStation.Id });
            }

Comment: I changed the station to Station. The if function does not get called up after the loop

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly it is the role id I want to add to the staffstation. The if function does not get called up in the loop. so it ends up returning null on the database

Comment: if you found my comment is useful please mark it as useful

Comment: @ Mohamed Adel the if function in the loop does not get called up talking bout the role id

Comment: that's mean the role id already assigned to this user